# I can't figure out why my array isn't filling here in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So, arrays are definitely not my strong suit. While testing this application in my driver class, I get the thrown exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.equals(Object)" because "this.order[x]" is null
at ics240assignment1.ShoppingCart.add(ShoppingCart.java:37)
at ics240assignment1.ShoppingCartDriver.main(ShoppingCartDriver.java:8)
In this area of the code, I'm just starting to add the first GroceryItem into the the ShoppingCart but it looks like the array is never filling  with anything and thus giving a "null" result. At least, that's what I think is going on.
Any obvious things I'm doing wrong here?

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    private String customer;
    private GroceryItem order[];
    private int numItems;

    public ShoppingCart() { // must instantiate an array called GroceryItems
        numItems = 0;
        order = new GroceryItem[10];
        customer = "";
    }

    public ShoppingCart(String name) {
        this.customer = name;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(String name, int size) {
        order = new GroceryItem[size];
        this.customer = name;

    }

    public boolean add(String name, double price, int quantity) {
        // changes made here
        String name1 = name;
        double price1 = price;
        int quant = quantity;
        int tempPlace = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        boolean full = false;
        if(order == null) {
            order[numItems++] = new GroceryItem(name, price, quantity);
            return true;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
            if (order[x].equals(name)) {
                tempPlace = x;// store place in array
                found = true;
            }

            if (found == true) {
                // get current qty, add to it, then update it
                int tempQty = order[tempPlace].getQty();
                tempQty = tempQty + quantity;

                order[tempPlace].setQty(tempQty);
                full = false;

            }

            else if (found == false) {
                for (int y = 0; y < order.length; y++) {
                    if (order[y] == null) {
                        order[y] = new GroceryItem(name, price, quantity);
                        full = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                full = true;
            }
        }

        if (full == false) {
            return true;
        }

        if (full == true) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // added all this
    public int find(String name) {
        boolean found = false;
        int location = 0;
        GroceryItem tempItem = new GroceryItem(name, 0, 0);
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
            if (order[x].equals(tempItem)) {
                found = true;
                location = x;

            }
        }

        if (found == false) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (found == true) {
            return location;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public double getTotalBeforeTax() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
            if (order[x] != null) {
                total += order[x].getPrice() * order[x].getQty();
            }
        }

        return total;
    }

    public double getTax(double taxRate) {
        double tax = 0;
           // Loops
           for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
               // Calculates tax
               tax += (order[i].getQty() * order[i].getPrice()) * (taxRate / 100.0);
           // returns total tax
           return tax;
    }

    public int getNumGroceryItems() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
            if (order[x] != null) {
                total += 1;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public int getTotalQuantity() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
            if (order[x] != null) {
                total += order[x].getQty();
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        output += customer;
        output += order;
        output += numItems;
        output += getNumGroceryItems();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Driver class for reference

```
public class ShoppingCartDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShoppingCart Randy = new ShoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart Sharron = new ShoppingCart();
        Randy.add("Eggs", 1.50, 1);
        System.out.println(Randy);

    }

}
```

Comment: This line will never be true: `if(order == null) {` because you assign `order`, the array, a value in the constructor.  Perhaps you meant to check if the item is null?  `if( order[numItems] == null ) {`

Comment: The only place you assign non-`null` values to the `order` array is after checking that the `order` array itself is `null`. That's (a) a guaranteed NPE and (b) a way to make sure the values of the array are never non-`null`. Double check that first condition

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

Because you initialise your "order" array size to 10 (under default constructor), when you loop over the array you will get some items being null.  You should consider looping with numitems as your limit, or use an alternate strcuture like ArrayList which is dynamically sizable.

But - also
Your array will never fill up because your if statement checks if order==null, which is always false, because order is an array.

Answer (score 0):

An array is like a little address book. `new GroceryItem[20]` doesn't make 20 grocery items. It merely creates a new address book with 20 pages on it; each page has room to write a pointer to a single grocery item on there. The book starts out **blank**: Room for 20 references, but it always starts out with blank pages (`null` values).

> `order = new GroceryItem[10];`

Right, so, whenever you make a shopping cart, its `order` value will always be referencing a freshly created little address book with 10 blank pages.

### Your constructors

The first constructor creates a new little address book with 10 pages, and then updates the `order` value to reference this address book (to point at it).

Your second constructor doesn't do anything, which means `order` will remain `null` (points at nothing; no address book exists at all).

Your third constructor creates an address book with the stated number of pages (provided via parameter), all blank.

That's your first problem - that second constructor is the odd one out, and this makes no sense.

### The add method

> `if(order == null) {`

This is true if you created this ShoppingCart with the second constructor, and can't be null otherwise. The very next line is then:

> `order[numItems++]`

This makes no sense. `[]` will 'dereference' - it will follow a reference. When you do that to a null value, you get a nullpointerexception. And it **is** `null` here - you *just* checked that! You'd have to presumable write something like: `order = new GroceryItem[10]` or whatnot. Or more likely, you never want to nullcheck `order`, and you always want to set up `order` to point at an actual GroceryItem array in every constructor (i.e. update constructor 2, and remove the `if` check because it's meaningless).

Thus, if you called the second constructor, this add method crashes right here. If you called the first or third, this `if` block is skipped, and we go on, with:

> ```
> for (int x = 0; x < order.length; x++) {
>           if (order[x].equals(name)) {
> ```

Same problem - `order[x]` exists (that'd be the instruction to find the address that leads to a GroceryItem by checking the xth page in your little address book. Unfortunately, initially this page is blank.

`.` also derefernces, and thus, NullpointerException will **always** occur here.

### The easy fix

Arrays are low-level constructors that you shouldn't be using. Use a `List<GroceryItem>` instead. such a list can grow and shrink. No nasty business with sizes and nullpointers.

### The hard fix

If this is some sort of homework assignment and you just must use arrays here, then keep in mind that the pages are *blank*, and you should check that before dereferencing (using that `.` dereferences). You can do so e.g. with `if (order[x] != null && order[x].getName().equals....`

Note that no 'real' java project (a project NOT meant to teach or explore) should never do it this way. Use a List.